# R - Cannot Download gz file from FTP Server

Tags: r, curl, download, ftp

I have been trying for three days now to download a file from an FTP server with R without a result. I have really tried everything and read all questions but still cannot manage.

The url is:

```
u <- "ftp://user:password@109.2.160.55/AGLO/2020/10/AGLO_00001_03-0_GDBX_1000077_202010032206_860101.CSV.gz"
```

When I copy paste this link in Firefox I can download the file, but with R I cannot. I tried `download.file`, `GET`, `writeBin`, `getURL`. All failed: `getURL` gives the following error:

```
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string: '\037‹\b\bøÙx_\0\003AGLO_00001_03-0_GDBX_1000077_202010032206_860101.CSV\0¬\\M³£¸’Ý¿_Áî­º\002I  XÉ¶®­*\fn>nÔ­MÇ›\231·èÍ¼\210î×\021óóç¤\004\006#¹.Œ§+¢ë’×¦Ž’TæÉ\017¡ÎUS*üï·\030ÿ±ßbñKüÛùtøþ\033#A–ýÆc\036ãgÁy,\177Ë%~f_ŽÝ{é~,é\v%}¡\\~ÐIN¿ÿùï?~ÿ\217¿þýÏ¿þ(\017±\034oY¾ýë¯?þû÷?ÿ$qù·Å/p\v÷\177{£òð]U½.umÊ¿\235»¦/{s~ƒ”\220–7ÓŸ¢Ã¿þø¯\177þã¯ÿ)ó¸ÈŠ\022_eEœã·îúz-K\031—í £¯ZÕÑW5´º+…H9/{Uéú¨K^BfNôsT©è]·­n\215ŽÊ2\021œ©²¦¯”e/æ»7e\fIy‹\231Ä_"ayF?ÈñÏýsåQUGüâ3ô¼H’d\t\177\024Hàgœ•ê=ºªópR„\235ç¬¼\002á¹VÇ\aðºRFy°y\b6Ç_xz¹d¯Àf<—I2Â.\030›\004\f°3\002­ZÓõ@\027\035Z£ê\023ÀÇ²(+\\7CwT}ÉJ\215¿»nè£þ¢\201\230Ô^>"§\033×ø3#çLäž¾éc›õ\035§‰`wàr\022\020pg-êøë »èÖjØCï\003çeý÷\037j\210êoM}n"ÝG×«ÆCÂ:£úï]S«è¢a_*°\034¹Z\016\036C\034XŽÜ¼œBð8YX\217»&ã‘\t=†›êz=´X…`yyÓ]g-G\177é¾Ü¾(üé¢¶9`\235Ñ­\031ÎXË\016\033*RÚwÏmèûgàešf|\001Þ]\023xžYËï/F·\235}\004p\tM{Òj\200·);Ý¾\033\230ýE\003úY_u\215‡`j,´Û¾\0^°8}iëf<\023Kå\217\002,àP2a­Éß\006‚%åM\r¦ªì“¸Ý`jã%°“{ú±AùiÊ_s;ô_ºÄî\004Öí0\vý4ÜTÿá+ÿÚœL5þv‡¹0ž’ÃxÁå¤’\025l\
```

There is no proxy problem whatsoever since to get the `u` url I am searching in the FTP directory.

How can I download this fing file ?

Also another way I could eventially work around this is using:

```
browseURL(u,
            browser = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe")
```

The issue with this is that it will open a Firefox browser that will:

1. Ask me if I am sure I want to go to this site and then
2. Ask me what I want to do with this file (not so much of a problem since I can choose a default to always download, but still I do not want to)

The issue with this is that simply I do not want to open a browser and I do not want to be asked if I want to go to the site and if I want to download. There are many files on this server so I want to do all of this automatically and I will need to be working in parllel, so having a browser pop up is not great, but if all else fails I can accept.

I am so desperate that I can give you the user name and password in private.

Comment: It looks like there might be issues with how your string is encoded, try to pass u to `enc2utf8`.

Comment: getURL(enc2utf8(u))  same error

Comment: Going a bit blind here: try using `httr` to download the file with something like `GET(u, write_disk("myfile.gz", overwrite=TRUE))`

Comment: I got this error but zeirdly it still worked! Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: So, did it work using `httr`? If so I can post my comment as an answer in order to close the question.

Comment: yes thank you. I had found an answer like this but the error through me off as I did not know that the file was being downloaded again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently downloading the file to disk using `httr` solved the problem. It is possible to combine `write_disk` and `httr::GET` to download files to disk in the following way:

```r
library(httr)

to_download <- "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"

# Download pdf to disk
GET(to_download, write_disk("dummy.pdf"))
```